# Having trouble adding text lables to pie chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

http://tributary.io/inlet/10932495

I can't seem to figure out why my text labels are not showing up on my chart. Help or suggestions? Link above shows my pie chart and my code as well as my csv data.

```
var arvadaData = tributary.arvadaPayments

var sumPayments = d3.sum(arvadaData, function(d) {return +d.payments;});

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var width = 527,
    height = 562,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var outerRadius = width/2;

var colorScale = d3.scale.category20(); //built in range of 20 colors

var arc = d3.svg.arc() //creates <path> elements using arc data
.outerRadius(width / 2)
.innerRadius(100);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d){ return +d.payments });

var g = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
.data(pie(arvadaData))
.enter()
.append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");


g.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i){return colorScale(i);})
    .attr("d", arc);

g.append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) +")"; })
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d){ return d[i].specialty; });
```

Comment: Post your code that relates to the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

The `text` elements are added and positioned correctly, but their content isn't set correctly. You're passing in the data coming from the pie layout -- the original data is available under the `.data` member in this case. That is, the expression to set the text should be

```
.text(function(d){ return d.data.specialty; });
```

Complete demo [here](http://tributary.io/inlet/11122969).